# Math.Round to every other int instead of every int

Tags: c#, math

This method round every value to an int:

```
transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Round(_mousePos.x), Mathf.Round(_mousePos.y));
```

How can I round it to every even number instead? i.e:

```
3.2f > 4
2.8f > 2
1.2f > 2
0.8f > 0
4.4f > 4
```

I guess one way of looking at it is to round to the closest even int.

Comment: Truncate and if the value is odd add one (or maybe subtract 1 if it's negative).  Only catch is what you'd do with 3.0.

Comment: Where did `Mathf` come from?

Comment: Sorry `Mathf` is from Unity. It does the same as c# `Math.Round`. Didn't even consider that they were diefferent things. My bad.

Comment: I think [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thats what I looked at to begiin with but it say `Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to the nearest integer. A parameter specifies how to round the value if it is midway between two numbers.`

Comment: What does `3.0f` round to?

Comment: Divide by 2, round, multiply by 2.  Decide what to do with odd integers.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Does not matter, as long as its either 2 or 4

Comment: @Green_qaue: One of the options there is rounding to the nearest even integer.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That only applies to `x.5` numbers and not to e.g. `3.0`.

Comment: @NetMage: Ah, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it as simple as?

```
private int round_to_even(float input)
{
return Mathf.Round(input / 2.0) * 2;
}
```

**Example:**

```
round_to_even(3.2);
==> Mathf.Round(1.6) * 2; 
==> 2.0 * 2;
==> 4;   // Final Answer.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct Mathf.Round and Math.Round perform the same.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html

The midpoint rounding mentioned in some of the question comments only has to do with decimals that are exactly .5 -- they will go to the even integer.  Other rounding is done exactly as expected; up or down to the nearest integer.

You'll need your own Round method of some kind.  You may need to modify the syntax a bit, but try something like this:

```
private float RoundToNearestEven(float input){
// if no decimal type make it even
if(input % 1 == 0)
{
    if(input % 2 != 0)
    {
        // arbitrary add 1
        return input + 1;
    }

    // already even
    return input;
}

bool isPositive = (input > 0);
float absInput = Mathf.abs(input)
float roundedInput = Mathf.Round(absInput);


if(isPositive && roundedInput % 2 == 0)
{
    return roundedInput;
}
else
{
    return -roundedInput;
}

// was rounded up
if(isPositive && input % 1 > .5)
{
    return roundedInput - 1;
}
else if (isPositive && input % 1 < .5)
{
    //was rounded down
    return roundedInput + 1;
}
else if (input % 1 > .5)
{
    //negative and was rounded up
    return -(roundedInput - 1);
}
else
{
    return -(roundedInut + 1);
}
```

}

I used float because the Mathf definition of round used it, may or may not be correct for your purposes, but you'll get the general idea.

```
        private int round_to_even(float input){return Mathf.Round(input / 2.0) * 2; }
```

Is much shorter, but has somewhat inconsistent behavior.  3 and 5 both will round to 4, 7 and 9 will both round to 8, etc.  This is due to the midpoint rounding of Mathf.Round().  If it is ok for your application it is a great, concise solution.